# DB2/400 Query - record format level identifiers for all tables in a library

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

We have multiple copies of the same library for testing, QA, development etc. consisting of hundreds of tables. Over time these libraries got out of sync and we run into a lot of level check problems. I would like to list all tables with a different Record Level Format Identifier from the corresponding tables in a model library. Is this possible using SQL? If not what other choices do we have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick peek into SYSTABLES didn't show anything, but the [QDBRTVFD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qdbrtvfd.htm) API has that information in the file definition header.  If APIs are not your thing, you can use `DSPFD FILE(somelib/*ALL) TYPE(*RCDFMT) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) FILEATR(*PF *LF) OUTFILE(QTEMP/RCDFMTS)` to create a file you CAN use SQL on.